# Semantic UI Vertical Align Icon and Menu

Tags: css, reactjs, semantic-ui, semantic-ui-react

I am currently trying to align a Icon and a text in a Menu.Item with Semantic UI React V.0.68.2.

Currently my HTML output looks like this:

```
<a class="active item pointer">
    <i aria-hidden="true" class="icon ti-icon ti-home large"></i>
    Dashboard
</a>
```

And my JSX like this:

```
<Menu vertical className="some classes" icon=''>
    <Menu.Item
    active={active}
    onClick={onClick}
    className="some class"
    >
        <Icon name="home" large /> Dashboard
   </Menu.Item>
</Menu>
```

I wrote a new Icon component to use my own Icon Font which looks like this. I tried to stay as close to the original Icon class from the React Implementation of Semantic UI.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import classnames from "classnames";

/**
 * @class Icon
 * @extends {Component}
 * @description Icon class for themify icons. Replacement for semantic ui Icon class
 */
class Icon extends Component {
    render() {
        var iconClass = classnames("icon ti-icon ti-" + this.props.name, {
            big: this.props.big,
            large: this.props.large,
            close: this.props.close
        });

        return (
            <i
                aria-hidden={true}
                className={this.props.close ? iconClass.replace("icon", "") : iconClass}
                onClick={this.props.onClick}
            />
        );
    }
}

export default Icon;
```

Now I want the Text and the Icon to be vertically centered but I can't get it to work, they text always seems to be at the top of its parent node. But actually I want it to appear vertically centered in the Menu.Item. with any size of the Icon. So when I change the size of the Icon to large the text should always be centered vertically. The size classes are the same as in Semantic UI.

[image: Dashboard misaligned]

Does anyone have an idea how to achieve this ? Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Have you tried using line-height? Or have you considered using flexbox?

Answer (score 0):

Hi you are facing a very common problem, possible solutions are depicted in the following codepen
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/XEKZwq

What I suggest you do is to wrap the text in a span so instead of:

```
<a class="active item pointer">
    <i aria-hidden="true" class="icon ti-icon ti-home large"></i>
    Dashboard
</a>
```

you do the following

```
<a class="active item pointer">
    <i aria-hidden="true" class="icon ti-icon ti-home large"></i>
    <span>Dashboard</span>
</a>
```

Once you've done this you can easily use the solution in the codepen above.